# How to convert oracle resultset to XML in VBScript

Tags: xml, oracle, vbscript, qtp

I am using QTP to query oracle DB and getting back values to write in a text file. How to convert the result to xml so that I can write XML to the text file.

```
strSQL ="select * from emp"
Set rs = objDBConn.Execute(strSQL)
```

to write to txt file

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outFile="C:\test.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
while not rs.EOF
row = ""
first_field = true
For Each field In rs.Fields
if (first_field = true) then
  row = field
  first_field = false
else
  row = row & " " & field
end if
Next  
objFile.Write row & vbCrLf
rs.MoveNext 
wend
```

Comment: What is the XML target schema?

Comment: I want column names to be xml tag for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not picky about the default naming, then the quickest way would be:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml( 'select * from emp') from dual
```

Comment: Right. Why do it in QTP if the engine can spit this out for free. +1

Comment: It works perfectly on my Oracle dev. But in QTP when I do strSQL ="select dbms_xmlgen.getxml( 'select * from emp') from dual";    Set rs= objDBConn.Execute(strSQL) I keep getting unspecified error when it tries to execute the query. So I thought I will convert it to xml using QTP

Answer (score 2):

You also can use the [.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to store the recordset into an .XML file (Remember to define `Const adPersistXML = 1`). The format may be better suited to other Microsoft XML tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think my personal approach would be to create an XML object, create child nodes from the resultant array from the query, append the child nodes to the parent, and then dump the .xml from the object into a text file.

I wrote the following general purpose function a long time ago and thought that you might find it helpful with what you are trying to do:

```
Function RequestAddChildNodeWithAttributes(NodeLocation, NodeName, NodeIndex, NodeAttributes, NodeValue)
Set parentNode = objXML.SelectNodes(NodeLocation).Item(NodeIndex)
Set newNode = objXML.CreateElement(NodeName)
For AttributeLoop = 0 To CInt(UBound(NodeAttributes) / 2) Step 2
    If NodeAttributes(AttributeLoop) <> "" Then newNode.setAttribute NodeAttributes(AttributeLoop), NodeAttributes(AttributeLoop + 1)
Next
If NodeValue <> "" Then newNode.Text = NodeValue
parentNode.appendChild newNode
End Function
```

Try running the following snippet to get an idea how how it works:

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.loadXML("<parent/>")
RequestAddChildNodeWithAttributes "/parent", "row1", 0, Array("header1", "result1", "header2", "result2", "header3", "result3"), "nodeValue1"
RequestAddChildNodeWithAttributes "/parent", "row2", 0, Array("header1", "result1", "header2", "result2", "header3", "result3"), "nodeValue2"
Print objXML.xml
```

note: you won't need anything in the NodeValue parameter for what you're doing so just pass in an empty string value and it won't write a value but will fill in the attributes.

You'd just need to get the headers from the array returned from the query (position 0 in the array), then loop through the rest of the rows*. Once it's generated, you can use the following code to create the result file and dump the .xml to it:

```
Set FileOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ResultFileName, true)
FileOut.Write objXML.xml
FileOut.Close
```

ETA: I can try to dig up the code for parsing the array that the query generates if you need me to.